# Cannot identify Javascript XHR API loading data to this page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to parse the EPG data at the below link. When I inspect the HTML using the below, all the program data is missing. I realise this is because it's being loaded async by Javascript, but I cannot figure out in Chrome Tools which is the API call as there seems to be a lot loaded into this page at once:

```
import requests

url = 'https://mi.tv/ar/programacion/lunes'
headers ={
    'Accept': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01',
    'Referer': outer,
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
    'X-KL-Ajax-Request': 'Ajax_Request',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }

r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
rr = r.text
print(rr)
```

...anyone identify for me what the correct API is? I can see there are API parameters given in the HTML, but I've not been able to assemble them into a working link and I cannot see anything with that URL root in chrome tools...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following shows the right url to use and how to return listings in a dict by channel key

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pprint import pprint

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://mi.tv/ar/async/guide/all/lunes/60', headers = headers)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
listings = {c.select_one('h3').text: list(zip([i.text for i in c.select('.time')], [i.text for i in c.select('.title')])) 
            for c in soup.select('.channel')}
pprint(listings)
```